# Height 100% no funciona - React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, component, estilos

estoy tratando de realizar un formulario de contacto para un proyecto y me he topado con un pequeño problema que me ha estancado, es lo unico que me falta :C.

### Problema

El problema radica en que a un contenedor que está a la izquierda de otro, quiero ponerle height 100% de manera que quede con la misma altura del que tiene al lado, pero no funciona.

Explicación Gráfica:
[image: Explicación Gráfica del problema]

Como logran observar la altura del div amarillo no es la del contenedor completo y la verdad no sé que hacer ya.

Código:
- Componente:

```
function Contact() {
  return (
    <ContactForm>
      <div className="info-ctn">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
        <p>Enter your data and your message</p>
      </div>
      <div className="form-ctn">
        <form action="">
          <h2>Send message</h2>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name" className="required">
              Names:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="mail" className="required">
              Email:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="mail" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="message" className="required">
              Message:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="message" />
          </div>

          <button type="submit">Send message</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </ContactForm>
  );
}
```

styled component del formulario:

```
export const ContactForm = styled.div`
  width: 90%;
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(181, 181, 181, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(181, 181, 181, 1);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(181, 181, 181, 1);
  .info-ctn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: ${COLORS.primaryColor};
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 44px;
      @media (max-width: 500px) {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
    p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
  .form-ctn {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    .form-group {
      width: 90%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 10px auto;
      label::after {
        content: '*';
        margin-left: 10px;
        color: #ff1818;
      }
      input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 18px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
        transition: border-bottom 300ms ease;
        &:focus {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #2cb2ff;
        }
      }
    }
    button[type='submit'] {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 20px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 2px;
      outline: none;
      padding: 5px 13px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: ${COLORS.primaryColor};
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    flex-direction: column;
    .form-ctn {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .info-ctn {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 30px 20px;
    }
  }
`;
```

Cómo pueden observar he tratado de poner min-heigth y height en 100%.

También encontré en algunos foros que debía de ponerle tanto al html como al body height 100% asi:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

cosa que ya he hecho en mi index.css pero aún así no funciona.

Agradecería una repuesta de alguno de ustedes compañeros, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba usando vh en vez de %

Comment: @JefferzonBol necesito una medeida que represente el 100% pero del contenedor padre, en este caso la medida de "VH" representaría el 100% pero de toda la screen osea de todo el body.
Igualmente por las dudas lo intenté y efectivamente no me sirve :C.

Comment: Estas usando flex, para que tenga el tamaño del padre que es display flex, dale flex-1, esto hace que ocupe todo el espacio disponible en un eje dependiendo si es row o column.

Comment: Para que el height100% te funcione el elemento padre debe tener una `height` definido; con  un `max-height` o un `min-height` no funciona. 
Intenta definir una altura al elemento padre y te funcionara.

Answer (score 0):

Sí defines una altura va a funcionar.

```css
body{
 background:#ff33;
}
.main{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  width:90%;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:auto;
  background:#fff;
  height:320px;
}

.info-ctn{
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  color:#000;
}

.form-ctn{
width:30%;
padding:20px;
}

input, button{
width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="info-ctn">
    <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
    <p>Enter your data and your message</p>
  </div>
      <div class="form-ctn">
        <form action="">
          <h2>Send message</h2>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name" className="required">
              Names:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="mail" className="required">
              Email:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="mail" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="message" className="required">
              Message:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="message" />
          </div>

          <button type="submit">Send message</button>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
```